# Replace URL with Site Title in Search Results

Tags: search, title, seo

When searching my company on a mobile device "Tattini Boots". You can see that the URL is displayed vs. the site title at the top (view image below). I am using Wordpress and was wondering where exactly this can be altered. Do I need to add a bread crumb title on the home page?

[image]

See alternative listings have the business name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is correct.

Google display in SERPs (Search Engine Results Pages) listing as follows:

- URL
- Page Title
- Page Description
- [ other attributes (potentially) ]

Your top result:

> Tattini Boots - 1860 | Italian English Riding Boots - U.S

Links to:

https://www.tattiniboots.com/

...your homepage.

[image]

Comment: View my edited screenshot. You can see that the listing below me (Tattini Riding) states the exact name, and not their url (tattiniriding.com). While my listing states the url (www.TattiniBoots.com) and not the name (Tattini Boots)

Comment: Their page is a category page `en-au/categories/riders-equipment` where as yours is the top level of your domain. With their page Google is picking up meta data such as the page being a category and will sometimes show that information to accentuate a result due to its relevance to the subject matter and search.

Comment: Wonderful; thank you for that confirmation! If I add a breadcrumb title to my home page I wonder if it would replace this URL?