# Change Image in Mobile Search Results

Tags: images, search, seo

When searching my company, "Tattini Boots", on a mobile device you will see that the following cut off image is displayed next to the search result (see image below). This is not the image that I have set in Yoast or the Featured Image for Search Results on my index page. Can someone dive into the source and allocate why this image is being chosen? This image is simply a slider overlay on the main page: www.TattiniBoots.com

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace URL with Site Title in Search Results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/356662/replace-url-with-site-title-in-search-results)

Comment: No, there is a big difference in the question. The first question is in regards to the breadcrumbs stating a URL over the site name. This question is in regards to the OG image associated with the google listing